# Pointing a parked domain to a Wordpress Subsite without changing url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

I have a client whose website develops & sells retirement villages in multiple locations, it's a Wordpress Multisite, with the main site being generic and the subsites are all the different locations. Basically we want to have an abbreviated domain for each location for advertising purposes that takes visitors to the correct location subsite, without changing the url, because we don't want to have to purchase SSL for every single domain/subsite.

so basically

locationA.com

when entered in the address bar goes to

https://mainsite.com/locationA

without changing the subsite url in the browser to LocationA.com - I know how to change the subsite domain via the wordpress admin settings but we don't want to change permalinks/urls unless there is absolutely no other way.

All the domains are parked at the mainsite's hosting, 
I've tried redirecting via the cPanel Alias settings going to https://mainsite.com/locationA, but it always just takes us to https://mainsite.com/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^locationA\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.locationA\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/mainsite\.com\/locationA\/" [R=301,L]
```

I've tried other various .htaccess edits from other forums but they either break the site or just do the same thing as above and takes us to the generic mainsite.
e.g.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^locationA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mainsite.com/locationA/ [L]
```

I don't really know what I'm doing with these, just trying things until something works.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, fixed it myself. The problem was that I added the domains as an 'Alias', redirection via CPanel worked when I added them as 'Addon Domains' instead.